# ActiveMQ client redelivery deep understanding

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ with 400 messages enqueued, redelivery delay is 5min (no Exp. backoff), and max redelivery attempts are 288. This is, more or less, in the worst case the message may be in the queue 24h ... or that was the idea of the original service designer but I have to experience a different behavior and the messages seem to hold in the queue much more.
The service is a WAR on a Tomcat.

My hypothesis is this:

- Redelivery is done at the client by caching the messages and related information
- so all redelivery logic details is stored at the client/consumer

What happens when tomcat is restarted and war is replaced by CI/CD process because of a new release?
... is that 24h counter reset?
... is there a max amount of tracked messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely yes.

All the redelivery policy control is done at the client-side (unless using broker plugin I have heard of) and there is no persistece so restarting the client will make all those counters to be reset and start again.

Answer (score 0):

The consumer would send an ack when the delivery is successfully, and the ActiveMQ (server) would decrease the message count.

In case of failure, considering the re-delivery policy, the Queue (server) would be responsible for taking counts of retry attempts, so yes, if you restart the Queue the counts would reset.

Comment: Well ... I am not restarting the queue (broker) but the client (consumer) ... and that's the point. I have confirmed that all that logic is handled at the client side (that is known) and there is no persistent state for those counters so restarting makes them to reset.

Comment: BTW server is NOT responsible for taking counts of retry attempts in ActiveMQ schema. The message it cached at the consumer level and the retry attempts are done at that level. That's unless you are using some plugin I have heard of.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for trying it out! So in case of multiple consumers/subscribers the retry count value is still stored on consumer(s) side?

Comment: The thing is the message is delivered to the consumer (at client-side) and cached there. The consumer won't send ACK signal, of course, until the retry policy flow is finished but neither the message will be sent to any other consumer. So, essentially, yes; even with multiple consumers the counter is stored on the client side